# Text primary key vs compound int

Tags: sqlite

I defined a field of unique IDs as primary key. I retrieve them from an external application in the form of a `string`: `"q:x:y:z"`, `q` `x` `y` and `z` all being being hex values

I currently store them as `TEXT`. I also use them in link-tables for n-n relationships.

I *could* split it and make them all ints and create a compound primary key.

How would a `TEXT` field `PRIMARY KEY` perform against a compound `PRIMARY KEY` of `(INT1, INT2, INT3, INT4)`? I could test this myself, but it involves a bit of setup. It would be really helpful to get input from people with hands-on experience. To give you an indication of size, I'm talking at most a few dozen million records, the (only theoretical) maximum being 500.000^2.

Comment: Benchmark both ways using typical queries and a decent sized sample of the final data and see for yourself. Also read https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html and consider that when designing your database schema.

Comment: I had hoped to not have to benchmark myself :) Did not know about the `without rowid`, that was very helpful.